# Weird unwanted multiple line break in ShareLaTeX

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, sharelatex

It's my first time using LaTeX and I've encountered something very strange. I have some mathematical/logic stuff that I wanted to put inside a verbatim tag (in order to enforce linebreaks and for formatting reasons), and somehow it gets surrounded by massive multiple-line linebreaks.

The LaTeX code is basically:

```
...random text...

\begin{verbatim}
logic stuff
\end{verbatim}

...some more text...
```

And for some reason, while formatted, the stuff inside the verbatim tags is separated to the other two columns by 3 or so blank lines, and I have no clue how to remove them as I don't know why they're even there in the first place. I've used the same exact formatting at other places in the document with no weird blank lines at all, and I can't find anything that's different from those cases either. This is how it looks in practice:

[image]

Comment: you give very few clues but I assume that you are using `book` or some other class that defaults to `\flushbottom` and that at the top of the next page there is some large unbreakable box, so the page you show has to b estretched.

Comment: maybe try to delete the empty line before and after the verbatime environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that might very well be true, as I said I'm not overly adept in LaTeX. I use a format known as "acm sigplan" that I just downloaded, and filled it in with my wanted categories. Can I force my document to not adhere to flushbottom somehow?

Comment: `\raggedbottom`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that worked wonders. Write your comment as an answer if you want me to accept your answer.

Comment: thanks for confirming it worked so I'll close as duplicate, cheers.